# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \ln(-\ln x)\frac{x^{a}}{\sqrt{-\ln x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am having trouble with the integral:

> Evaluate
> $$\int_0^1 \ln(-\ln x)\frac{x^{a}}{\sqrt{-\ln x}}dx$$

**My Attempt**

let $u=-\ln(x)\rightarrow x=e^{-u}\rightarrow dx=-e^{-u}du$ bounds: $(0,1)\rightarrow (\infty,0)$
$$
\int_0^1 \ln(-\ln x)\frac{x^{a}}{\sqrt{-\ln x}}dx=\int_{\infty}^0 \ln(u)\frac{e^{-au}}{\sqrt{u}}(-e^{-u}du)=\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(u)\frac{e^{-(a+1)u}}{\sqrt{u}}du
$$
let $(a+1)u=w \rightarrow du=\frac{dw}{a+1}$

$$
\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(u)\frac{e^{-(a+1)u}}{\sqrt{u}}du=\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(w/(a+1))\frac{e^{-w}}{\sqrt{w/(a+1)}}(\frac{dw}{a+1})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(w/(a+1))\frac{e^{-w}}{\sqrt{w}}dw
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(w))\frac{e^{-w}}{\sqrt{w}}dw-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(a+1))\frac{e^{-w}}{\sqrt{w}}dw=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\int^{\infty}_0 \ln(w))\frac{e^{-w}}{\sqrt{w}}dw-\frac{\ln(a+1)\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a+1}}
$$

How can progress from here? Have I used the correct method? thank you for your time.

Comment: You asked the previous question 25 minutes ago, so pretty fast. This one has no closed form using Wolfram Alpha for $a=1$. Finally, what is the context?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I do a set of integrals and ask about the ones I cannot answer.

Comment: @hwood87. Here's you answer in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29w%5C%2841%29Power%5Be%2C-w%5D%5C%2841%29%2CSqrt%5Bw%5D%5D%2C%7Bw%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D). I am not sure how to evaluate that manually.

Answer (score 3):

Using http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E19, http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4.E13 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4.E6, we find
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\log u\frac{{e^{ - (a + 1)u} }}{{\sqrt u }}du} & = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\log t\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{\sqrt t }}dt}  - \frac{{\log (a + 1)}}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{\sqrt t }}dt} 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\Gamma '\!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2}} \right) - \frac{{\log (a + 1)}}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\Gamma \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2}} \right)
\\ &  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\Gamma \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\psi\!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2}} \right) - \frac{{\log (a + 1)}}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\Gamma \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{2}} \right)
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\sqrt \pi  ( - \gamma  - 2\log 2) - \frac{{\log (a + 1)}}{{\sqrt {a + 1} }}\sqrt \pi
\\ &
 =-
\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{a + 1}}} \left( { \gamma  + \log (4(a + 1))} \right).
\end{align*}